# How to get generics with completion and resultType working?

Tags: swift

I'm currently writing and database access class for two database APIs (realm and Firestore). With the intention to slim down the code i try to solve the whole thing a little sleaker with generics (#1). Unfortunately, it's not working. Where do I miss the point?

I tried with defining associatedtypes (#2) and setting them within the RealmAccessStragy class. But on this point the compiler returns error if try to access the protocol via the PersistenceController.

I am grateful for any help!

### **APPROACH #1**

```swift
enum DataResult<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

protocol DataApiAccess: AnyObject {
func read<U, T>(primaryKey: U, completion: @escaping ((DataResult<T>) -> Void))
}

class RealmAccessStrategy {
    ...
    func read<U, T>(primaryKey: U, completion: @escaping ((DataResult<T>) -> Void)) {
        guard let realmObject = realmInstance.object(ofType: realmObjectType, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else {
            completion(.failure(RealmAccessError.noObject))
            return
        }

        completion(.success(realmObject)) // ERROR: Member 'success' in 'DataResult<_>' produces result of type 'DataResult<T>', but context expects 'DataResult<_>'
    }
}


// Later implementation
class PersistenceController {
    private let strategy: DataApiAccess

    init(use: DataApiAccess) {
        self.strategy = use
    }

    func load<U, T>(primaryKey: U, completion: @escaping ( (DataResult<T>) -> Void ) ) {
        strategy.read(primaryKey: primaryKey, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

**ERROR: Member 'success' in 'DataResult<*>' produces result of type 'DataResult', but context expects 'DataResult<*>'**

### **APPROACH #2**

```swift
enum DataResult<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

protocol DataApiAccess {
    associatedtype ReturnType

    func read(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType, completion: @escaping DataApiHandler<ReturnType>)
}

class RealmAccessStrategy: DataApiAccess {

    ...

    // Typealias
    internal typealias ReturnType = Object

    func read(primaryKey: Any, completion: @escaping ((DataResult<Object>) -> Void)) {
        guard let realmObject = realmInstance.object(ofType: realmObjectType, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else {
            completion(.failure(RealmAccessError.noObject))
            return
        }

        completion(.success(realmObject))
    }
}


class PersistenceController {
    private let strategy: DataApiAccess // ERROR: Protocol 'DataApiAccess' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

    init(use: DataApiAccess) {
        self.strategy = use
    }

    ...

    }
}
```

**ERROR: Protocol 'DataApiAccess' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

Comment: Well the first question would be why you are defining DataResult when Swift already _has_ a Result type. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result It is very powerful and cool and you're going to be much happier using it.

Comment: yes, I know. But it does make no difference concerning the main problem. As far as I can see?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set **variable generic protocols** but you can set **methods**

**Example code below**

- Create enum for base result:

  ```
  enum DataResult<T> {
      case success(T)
      case failure(Error)
  }
  ```

---

```
    ///Set a protocol generic methods:
    protocol DataApiAccess {
        func read<T: Codable>(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType, completion: @escaping (DataResult<T>) -> Void)
    }

    class RealmAccessStrategy: DataApiAccess {

        func read<T: Codable>(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType, completion: @escaping (DataResult<T>) -> Void) {
            // Read data from database
        }
    }

    class NetworkAccessStrategy: DataApiAccess {


        func read<T: Codable>(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType, completion: @escaping (DataResult<T>) -> Void) {
             // Get data from request
        }
    }

    class PersistenceController {

        private let strategy: DataApiAccess

        init(use: DataApiAccess) {
            // Set dependency inversion for offline or online state
            self.strategy = use
        }

        func foo() {
             // TODO
            //strategy.read(primaryKey: <#T##PrimaryKeyType#>, completion: <#T##(DataResult<Decodable & Encodable>) -> Void#>)
        }


    }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks your support. but I can't get it running. `func read<T: Codable>(primaryKey: Int, completion: @escaping (DataResult<T>) -> Void) {
        guard let realmObject = realmInstance.object(ofType: realmObjectType, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else {
            completion(.failure(RealmAccessError.noObject))
            return
        }
        
        completion(.success(realmObject))
    }` results in ERROR: Member 'success' in 'DataResult<_>' produces result of type 'DataResult<T>', but context expects 'DataResult<_>'

Comment: You can use Result class in swift